# Cannot read property 'valideDate' of null in angular

Tags: angular, validation

i am trying to add some validation to date and time.

1. Date must be less than than current Date.
2. start time must be less than end time.
3. if date equal current date start and end time each must be less than current time.

First i try only case number (1) date less than current date.

this my code:

i have in mat-dialog 3 input (date, start time, end time):

```
<ng-template #callAPIDialog>
  <form [formGroup]="rangeForm">


    
    <div style="padding: 10px;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date</label>
        <input
          type="date"
          class="form-control"
          style="cursor: pointer; padding-left: 1rem;"
          formControlName="date"
        />
        <div *ngIf="date.errors.valideDate">
          Errors
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Start Time</label>
        <input
          type="time"
          class="form-control"
          style="cursor: pointer; padding-left: 1rem;"
          formControlName="startTime"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>End Time</label>
        <input
          type="time"
          class="form-control"
          style="cursor: pointer; padding-left: 1rem;"
          formControlName="endTime"
        />
      </div>
      <br>
      <div align="end" style="text-align: center;
      ">

        <button style="margin-right: 10px;" class="btn btn-primary" mat-button matDialogClose="cancel">
            Cancel
        </button>
        <button mat-button matDialogClose="submit" class="btn btn-danger" [disabled]="!rangeForm.valid"
        style="cursor: pointer;">
            Submit
        </button>

    </div>

    </div>
  </form>
</ng-template>
```

in component.ts:

```
  this.rangeForm = new FormGroup({
    date: new FormControl(this.dateDialog, [Validators.required, ValidatorsSettings.valideDate]),
    startTime: new FormControl(starttime, Validators.required),
    endTime: new FormControl(endtime, Validators.required),
    
  },);

  let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(this.callAPIDialog);
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
  // Note: If the user clicks outside the dialog or presses the escape key, there'll be no result
  if (result !== undefined) {

    if (result === "submit") {
      if(this.rangeForm.valid){
        this.historyDateHanlder.changeHistoryDate(this.rangeForm.value);
    
        this.router.navigate([....]);
  
      }
  
    } else if (result === "cancel") {
    }
  }
  });
```

in case of validaDate method :

```
  static valideDate(control: FormControl) : ValidationErrors {
    var currentDate = new Date();

    if ((control.value < = currentDate.getTime())) {
        // invalid, return error object
        return { 'valideDate' : true } ;

    }
     else {
       // valid, return null
       return null ;
     }
  }
```

But not work i receive this error :

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'valideDate' of null
    at ...
```

Comment: Where the error comes from is important as you reference it in two places. However, this is possibly because `date.errors` does not exist - check it exists before trying to reference `date.errors.valideDate` (assuming that's the line where the error is)

Comment: because by default i have date current value but here he take date null i don't know why.

Comment: Because date is inside of your form, `rangeForm.get('date').errors?.valideDate` - errors can be null which is why i have included the safety operator when trying to access valideDate.